# Ubuntu 17.10 on Thinkpad Yoga won't sleep

Tags: suspend, power-management, lenovo, 17.10, thinkpad

I've done a fresh install on my Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga S1 with Ubuntu 17.10.
The machine won't go sleep. Actually, it seems it does try to put the system into the sleep mode then instantly wakes up showing the login screen. Both menu option (Pause) and closing lid cause the same, invalid behaviour. I've already configured via Gnome Tweak to fall asleep on lid close but it does not change behaviour.

Looking forward to any help.
Is there any method to investigate, what causes immediate wake-up?

Regards,

Piotr

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Lenovo Yoga Thinkpad. I used your solution and simply created script in init.d:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Disable XHC wake
#
  case "$1" in
  start)    sudo sh -c "echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
            ;;
  stop) sudo sh -c "echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
        ;;
  esac
exit 0
```

Then link to rc5.d.
Maybe not the smartest solution, but worked for me.

Comment: Me too - Yoga S1 with Ubuntu 20.04 always wakes up a few seconds after putting it to hibernate. Didn't get your solution to work, but I put OP's line from below `sh -c "echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup" ` in a script and have it started @reboot by sudo crontab -e. Still less smart, but it works and I've observed no side effects so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would be curious to see what you get while running "tail -f /var/log/syslog" being run while you suspend the system.

To help with comparison, I closed the lid for about thirty seconds and then opened it back up in order to produce said log. I have copied it to [PasteBin.](https://pastebin.com/AZJMykTZ)

I'm curious to see what your log says during those points of trying to sleep.

Comment: The [syslog](https://pastebin.com/mCpWHLU2) is here.
I just found a temporary solution - the reason is an XHC (XHCI) controller waking up my notebook even if there are no devices attached to it (at least external ones). Issuing:

     sudo sh -c "echo XHC  > /proc/acpi/wakeup"

helps but I need to it every restart.